# Using SD card module on SPI1 instead of SPI0 raspberry Pico with Arduino core

Tags: sd-card, spi, arduino-ide, raspberry-pi-pico

So I am trying to connect and then launch the SD card reader to Raspberry Pico using SPI1 and not the default pico one because the default one is taken by a LoRa module.

I am using the [arduino core](https://github.com/earlephilhower/arduino-pico).

```c
  SPI1.setRX(12); // 16 12
  SPI1.setTX(15); // 20 15
  SPI1.setSCK(14); // 19 14
  SPI1.setCS(13); // 17 13
```

I figured out this the way to define my SPI1 pins, but I still have no clue how to launch the SD card library on SPI1 and not the default SPI0.

I know that the defining code is right because I tested the SD card module on alternative SPI0 pins and it worked. I also asked the wise man that created the core how to do it and that's what he replied:

*"There are 2 SPI port, SPI and SPI1. You can use the 2nd port, SPI1 at the same time as SPI. I don't think it's safe from the SPI protocol to change pins between transactions (glitches/etc. might upset the devices)."*

But I still have no clue on how to run a SPI device on SPI1.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `SD.begin(SD_SPI1_CSn, SPI1);` after setting the SPI pins